# How to get sum of array for specific position?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have an array:

```
<cfset fullarray = listtoArray (listofcollumnvalues)>
```

And it had for example:

```
fullarray[1]=20
fullarray[2]=11
fullarray[3]=4
fullarray[4]=12.2
etc.
```

And I wanted to add the sum of the the X position below number:
for example if I wanted the sum of the second element and below

2 + 3 + 4=  27.2

Comment: Yes, get a sub array from the source array consisting of the range you want to sum, then sum them. Or, do a for loop just over the indexes you want to sum.

Comment: Better yet, ignore the array and loop though the original list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ColdFusion 10 introduced the [`ArraySlice`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ArraySlice) function. It returns an array when you give it an array, a starting location, and an optional length. So `ArraySlice(myArray,3,4)` would return a "sub-array" with the elements that start at position 3 and includes 4 elements.

Based on your example:

```
mySum = ArraySum(ArraySlice(fullarray,2))
```

If you're on CF 9 or below, you can use a UDF. At CFLib.org there is

- [arraySlice](http://www.cflib.org/udf/arraySlice)
- [arraySlice2](http://www.cflib.org/udf/arraySlice2)

*Warning!* `arraySlice` uses "start" and "end" element arguments, while `arraySlice2` uses "start" and "length" arguments, like the built-in CF10 function.

Comment: great why cant it be 9

Comment: @anatp_123: It wouldn't be too difficult to write your own arrayslice function. You don't have to though, since someone has already written a couple that you can get from CFLib.org.

Comment: Side note, since the new CF function is also named ArraySlice, you might want to name the udf something else to avoid potential conflicts when you upgrade.

Answer (score -1):

Here's something that will work on older versions.

```
<cfscript>
function listSum(listStr)
{
  var delim = ",";
  if(ArrayLen(Arguments) GTE 2) 
    delim = Arguments[2];
  return ArraySum(ListToArray(listStr, delim));
}
</cfscript>
```

Simply envoke it as `#listSum(MyListOrArray)#`

Comment: This appears to sum the entire array.  He only wants the sum of part of it.

Answer (score -1):

This is a formatted comment.  You define your array as this:

```
<cfset fullarray = listtoArray (listofcollumnvalues)>
```

The variable, `listofcollumnvalues` looks like it might represent results of a query object.  If that's the case, You might be doing more work than necessary, because each column of a query is effectively an array.  Consider for example this query:

```
<cfquery name = "queryName">
select field1, numericalField
from etc
</cfquery>
```

You can actually do stuff like this:

```
numericalFieldSum = ArraySum(queryName['numericalField'];
```

It's not exactly what you want, but it illustrates that you might not need your initial command.

Continuing with the assumption that you started with a query, a query of queries might give you what you want.

```
<cfquery name = "mySum" dbtype = "query">
select sum(numericalField) theSumIWant
from queryName
where your conditions are met
</cfquery>
```

Of course, if `listofcollumnvalues` does not come from a query, you should declare this answer to be useless twaddle and downvote accordingly.